# Hololens: how to render element visible only in AR, but not in mixed reality capture

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, hololens, windows-mixed-reality

I'm making a presentation of someone using the Hololens that is duplicated on a big screen. For duplication it uses the device portal's mixed reality capture option (live stream).

I need to render a tool tip to be visible only to the person with the Hololens - but invisible to the people watching it on the big screen.

From what I've seen, the only difference in rendering between the two is that I can render black on the live stream (if I omit rendering the alpha channel) with it being invisible on the Hololens due to the way it's screen works. This is unfortunately useless to me, as I need to show something to the Hololens viewer, not big screen viewers.

Any ideas on how can I make part of the content visible only to the hololens user?
I can't use spectator view due to other constraints (I need first person view).

Comment: I don't think you can. The MRC is intended to capture everything so that people watching see exactly what the wearer sees. Microsoft might enable "recording window" style rendering in the future, but as far as I know, it does not currently exist. You can render black on the MRC because of how the hololens *device* itself *physically* renders things (it does not have the ability to block out real world light as it is an additive-only display system).

Answer (score 2):

Found a solution, not the best one possible, but usable.

I render the tooltip objects only to the right eye, as only the contents of the left eye are included in the live view.

For anyone wondering, in a shader, there is a magic value of `unity_StereoEyeIndex` that has the value 1 or 0, depending on the eye. To use this value, [it first needs to be set up](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SinglePassStereoRendering.html).

If anoyone has an idea how can I do this without sacrificing stereoscopy, I'll be happy to hear about it.